# The high power integral

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Im trying to solve  the indefinite integral
 $$\int\frac{x}{(x^2+4)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

I tried applying polynimial division and breaking to partial fractions but it didnt help...are there any other options?

Comment: Just as Mathmo123 answered, you face the situation where you have something looking as $\frac{u'}{u^3}$. So ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the substitution $u=x^2+4$.

Comment: simple and sufficent, thanks

Answer (score 11):

With questions like this, before jumping into anything more complicated like substitutions and partial fractions, sometimes its a good idea just to stop and think for a second, "*what would I expect the solution to look like?*" This won't always work, but when it does, it's a massive time saver.

Looking at this, rewriting it as $\int x(x^2+4)^{-3}dx$, I'd guess a solution of the form $$k(x^2 + 4)^{-2}$$
where $k$ is some constant that I need to find. I can then differentiate this expression to find out what $k$ should be:$$\frac{d}{dx}k(x^2 + 4)^{-2} = -4kx(x^2+4)^{-3} = x(x^2 + 4)^{-3}$$so $k=-\frac14$.

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $x^2=t$ to get $2xdx=dt$ and $dx=dt/(2x)$.  Substituting in the integral you get $$ \int\frac{1}{2(t+4)^3} \, \mathrm{d}t$$

The indefinite integral is therefore easily obtained as

$$-\frac{1}{4(t+4)^2}+c$$

and making the inverse substitution we finally get

$$-\frac{1}{4(x^2+4)^2}+c$$